# unable to create session: control: unable to connect to initial hosts: Invalid Cosmos DB account or key

Tags: cassandra, azure-cosmosdb, gocql

I have been trying to connect to cosmos cassandra db using gocql.

```
func GetSession(cosmosCassandraContactPoint, cosmosCassandraPort, cosmosCassandraUser, cosmosCassandraPassword string) *gocql.Session {
    clusterConfig := gocql.NewCluster(cosmosCassandraContactPoint)
    port, err := strconv.Atoi(cosmosCassandraPort)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    clusterConfig.Port = port
    clusterConfig.ProtoVersion = 4
    clusterConfig.Authenticator = gocql.PasswordAuthenticator{Username: cosmosCassandraUser, Password: cosmosCassandraPassword}
    clusterConfig.SslOpts = &gocql.SslOptions{Config: &tls.Config{MinVersion: tls.VersionTLS12}}

    clusterConfig.ConnectTimeout = 10 * time.Second
    clusterConfig.Timeout = 10 * time.Second
    clusterConfig.DisableInitialHostLookup = true

    // uncomment if you want to track time taken for individual queries
    //clusterConfig.QueryObserver = timer{}

    // uncomment if you want to track time taken for each connection to Cassandra
    //clusterConfig.ConnectObserver = timer{}

    session, err := clusterConfig.CreateSession()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Failed to connect to Azure Cosmos DB", err)
    }

    return session
}
```

I have been getting the following error :

```
unable to create session: control: unable to connect to initial hosts: Invalid Cosmos DB account or key
```

Not sure what the issue here is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your account or key is wrong.

First,please make sure your API is CASSANDRA API.You can check at here.
[image]

Second,please make sure your account or key is right.

```
COSMOSDB_CASSANDRA_CONTACT_POINT=<value for "CONTACT POINT">
COSMOSDB_CASSANDRA_PORT=<value for "PORT">
COSMOSDB_CASSANDRA_USER=<value for "USERNAME">
COSMOSDB_CASSANDRA_PASSWORD=<value for "PRIMARY PASSWORD">
```

You can find them here:
[image]

More details,you can refer to this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/create-cassandra-go).
Hope this can help you.

Comment: I did make sure it that it is the Cassandra API and also did make sure that keys match. Currently passed a hardcoded values to the GetSession function, Is it necessary to specify it as env variables?

Comment: you can try it.I set environment variables and it works.

Comment: I passed a hardcoded values to the GetSession function just now.It also works fine.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that you solve it.If my answer help you,can you mark it an answer?Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like you've configured the necessary options for the SSL/TLS configuration, particularly the certificates.

I haven't connected to a Cosmos DB before so I'm not sure of the certs/keys required but I previously helped someone configure the gocql driver with the right TLS settings in this post -- https://community.datastax.com/questions/3753/.

In their environment, they needed to provide the certs and keys to connect as follows:

```
certPath, _ := filepath.Abs("/home/erick/astra-bundle/cert")
keyPath, _ := filepath.Abs("/home/erick/astra-bundle/key")
caPath, _ := filepath.Abs("/home/erick/astra-bundle/ca.crt")
cert, _ := tls.LoadX509KeyPair(certPath, keyPath)
caCert, _  := ioutil.ReadFile(caPath)
caCertPool := x509.NewCertPool()
caCertPool.AppendCertsFromPEM(caCert)
tlsConfig := &tls.Config{
    Certificates: []tls.Certificate{cert},
    RootCAs:      caCertPool,
}
cluster.SslOpts = &gocql.SslOptions{
    Config: tlsConfig,
    EnableHostVerification: false,
}
```

Details are in the post above. I hope this helps. Cheers!